# Java OAuth2 Authentication for Outlook 365

Tags: java, azure, jakarta-mail, outlook-restapi

I have a Java program which tries to use the Eclipse Jakarta APIs to connect with OAuth 2.0 to Outlook 365. Here is what I did:

Azure portal:

- Created a new App registration with type "Accounts in any organization and personal Microsoft account"
- Added API permission: Microsoft Graph > Delegated permission "email" and "IMAP.AccessAlsUser.All" / "POP.AccessAsUser.All"
- Created a new client secret

Java Program:

- Changed a working application to use OAuth 2.0 authentication
- Changed to send the "Client Secret Value" instead of the normal password

Debug Output:

```
Mail property mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable: true
Mail property mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms: XOAUTH2
Mail property mail.imaps.port: 993
Mail property mail.store.protocol: imaps
Mail property mail.imaps.partialfetch: false
Mail property mail.mime.decodetext.strict: false
Mail property mail.imaps.peek: true
Mail property mail.mime.charset: UTF-8

DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 2.0.0
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.partialfetch: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: peek
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [WgBSADAAUAAyADcAOABDAEEAMAAxADAAMwAuAEMASABFAFAAMgA3ADgALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=xxx@outlook.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

How can I find out, what is missing or what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Could u pls share your tutorial sample or your own code snipaste. By the way, can this [doc on accessing outlook](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/FAQ#outlook) help you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is quite a complex program and hard to isolate the authentication step. But the program works fine for normal (password) logins. The only change was to force XOAUTH2 login and pass the client secret value instead of the password to the connect().

Comment: My guess is that the error comes from a missing step in the Azure portal to enable OAuth 2.0 authentication.